# How do I move the cursor to the end the content in the RadEditor?

Tags: telerik, radeditor

I am using a RadEditor and a button that puts some text into the RadEditor. I was wondering how after I click the button and place the content in the RadEditor, I can get the cursor to be at the end of the content. For now it is just at the beginning when i give the RadEditor focus.

Please Help!!

oshi

Answer (score 0):

```
var editor = *you'll need to provide the $find() functionality to get an instance of your page's editor*;

editor.setFocus(); 
var doc = editor.get_document();

doc.execCommand("SelectAll", null, false); 

//Collapse selection to the end 
editor.getSelection().collapse();
```